# Оптимальное количество элементов подгружаемых из SQLite в RecyclerView за один запрос

Tags: android, sqlite, recyclerview

Есть новостной агрегатор. Статьи грузятся из сети, и хранятся в локальной `SQLite`. UI организован стандартно: `RecyclerView`, элементами которого являются превью статей.

Вопрос следующий: *как оптимально организовать подгрузку данных в* `RecyclerView` из `SQLite`, если на экране помещается ≈ 3 элемента?

Поясню: в данном вопросе временем загрузки статей из сети, их размещением в БД и временем преобразования статей в превью пренебрегаем. Интересует механизм подгрузки элементов в `RecyclerView` за один запрос и организация этой подгрузки. Стандартный механизм (загружаем сколько-то элементов -> пользователь прокручивает список до конца -> загружаем новую порцию элементов) не подходит.

Например, возможно *стоит ловить скроллинг на середине списка и уже тогда начинать подгрузку новых данных*? Кроме того, возможно у уважаемого сообщества есть опыт о том, *какое количество элементов из* `SQLite` *оптимально забирать за один запрос?* Т.к. есть подозрение, что загрузка 3 элементов из `SQLite` будет примерно равна по времени загрузке 30 элементов, т.к. б*о*льшая часть времени тратится на саму транзакцию, но уже скажем запрашивать 300 элементов за запрос будет неоптимально.

Comment: за один запрос нужно "забирать" все нужные данные, нет никакого смысла делить их на маленькие части. Такое применимо к сетевым запросам, но никак не к локальным БД. Cursor сам подгрузит что надо, в нужном ему количестве, насколько мне помниться. В любом случае не стоит делать из этого проблему

Comment: вы как-то сильно заморачиваетесь. последний пиксель или самсунг вам за секунду загрузит с базы овер9000 элементов. дешевенький мейзу начнет пыхтеть уже на пяти

Comment: все эти "подгрузить еще" были придуманы ради экономии трафика сети. локально грузите сразу всё

Comment: @SviatVolkov и @pavloff в целом согласен с вами, действительно немного заморачиваюсь и именно для оптимизации на маломощных устройствах. С тем, чтобы грузить "все нужные данные", а не порциями, не согласен. Т.к. даже если устройство мощное, то как минимум нужно смотреть размер этих данных. У `SQLiteCursor` есть буфер `CursorWindow`, размером около 2 MB. И если ваш запрос вытаскивает > 2 MB, уже будут относительно большие накладные расходы по времени со стороны `SQLiteCursor`.

Comment: О проблемах производительности с `SQLiteCursor` при больших запросах см. в [этой статье](https://medium.com/google-developers/large-database-queries-on-android-cb043ae626e8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался в проблеме. Представлю свой ответ.

Во-первых, почему для достаточно больших списков не стоит загружать сразу все данные для `RecyclerView` из `SQLite`:

1. Нет смысла грузить данные, которые пользователь, возможно, не увидит.
2. Если *при той же отзывчивости* интерфейса (без тормозов), мы можем обеспечить плавную подгрузку данных и, при этом, наше *приложение будет кушать меньше памяти*, то почему бы не сделать так?
3. Использование `SQLiteCursor` имеет ту особенность, что при выборке данных размером больше 2 MB появляются дополнительные расходы по времени на выборку каждых следующих 2 MB данных. Речь о том, что размер используемого `SQLiteCursor` буфера строк (`CursorWindow`) около 2 MB. Более подробно об этой проблеме см. в этой статье: [оригинал](https://medium.com/google-developers/large-database-queries-on-android-cb043ae626e8) (en) и [перевод на русский](https://ziginsider.github.io/large-database-queries-on-android/).

Существуют решения по плавной подгрузке данных в `RecyclerView` из `SQLite`: см., например, [этот цикл статей](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/) (en).

Есть [данные](https://www.techyourchance.com/data-paging-lists/), что оптимально загружать за один раз не менее чем в 10 раз больше элементов `RecyclerView`, чем помещается на экране. Т.е., если на экране 3 элемента, подгружаем за один раз около 30. Подгрузку следующей порции данных, следует начинать на половине или 2/3 скроллинга до конца списка. Это общие советы, т.к. стоит учитывать размер данных, возможное их преобразование в POJO-объекты для списка, особенности реализации `RecyclerView`.

Наконец, есть библиотека от Google [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) (еще не вышла в релиз 1.0), которая призвана в том числе решать проблему, затронутую в вопросе.

Еще один пример, реализация подгрузки c использованием RxJava ([1 часть](https://habrahabr.ru/post/268991/), [2 часть](https://habrahabr.ru/post/271875/)).

Comment: я понял то, что хотя CursorWindow и имеет некоторые недостатки в алгоритме, все же он справится с задачей подгрузки данных лучше, чем вы будете писать свой алгоритм подгрузки "порциями" (не говоря уже о том, что и вам не удастся избежать 90% проблем CursorWindow, перечисленных в статье или предется писать очень сложный буфер, который будет давать очень малое преимущество в скорости, так как подавляющее большинство современных устройств достаточно мощные для таких задач). В общем, я по прежнему уверен, что "заморачиваться" подгрузкой данных при работе SQLite нет никакого практического смысла.

Comment: про PagingLibrary как то упустил, посмотрю на досуге. Так же стоит заметить, что большинство проблем из статьи решается использованием CursorLoader (фоновая подгрузка и менеджмент курсора). Поставлю плюс, за проделанную работу, которая содержит много полезной информации, хотя с выводами я не согласен

Comment: Если говрить о связке SQLite и POJO, то есть все резоны отказаться от этой связки и использовать nosql БД Realm или ObjectBox (для более простых задач) или тот же ORM Room, который сейчас активно двигает Google (хотя он и сущестаенно проигрывает nosql решениям в скорости) , хотя учитывая ваше стремление к "экономии на спичках" они могут вас и не устроить (по факту преобразования реляционной структуры в POJO "в ручную" отнимут брльше ресурса, чем низкоуровневые реализации в nosql БД).

Comment: За советы благодарю. Переписывать `SQLiteCursor`, конечно, не собираюсь. Вы правы, по поводу Realm, как раз рассматриваю эту ORM, как замену SQLite на будущее. По поводу `CursorLoader`, видел в связке с `ContentProvider` - действительно удобно, но по скорости не выигрывает.  Paging Library Google как раз совместно с Room и продвигает в массы.

Answer (score 4):

@pavloff, конечно все верно расписал:

> за один запрос нужно "забирать" все нужные данные, нет никакого смысла делить их на маленькие части. Такое применимо к сетевым запросам, но никак не к локальным БД. Cursor сам подгрузит что надо, в нужном ему количестве, насколько мне помниться. В любом случае не стоит делать из этого проблем

Но проблема в том, что `RecyclerView` из коробки не умеет поддерживать адаптер с курсором, то есть надо самому заморачиваться с изобретением адаптера, который будет читать из БД или же придумывать адаптер, который работает поверх `Cursor`, по аналогии с `CursorAdapter`, который имеется в комплекте `ListView`.

К счастью умные люди уже все написали все. Возьмите [RecyclerViewCursorAdapter](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59) - подайте ему на вход заранее подготовленный `Cursor` и будет вам счастье

Comment: Спасибо! Хорошее решение. Пока, чтобы не изобретать велосипед, смотрю в сторону [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html)

Comment: Есть [мнения](https://medium.com/@porten/android-paging-list-adapter-comparison-8fe8885dbe71), что paging library чуть шустрее `Cursor`