# Большой объем данных для RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть БД с таблицей в которой около 50 тыс. записей. Необходимо их вывести в `RecyclerView`.

Скажите если я использую адаптер, который использует коллекцию для вывода данных в список не будет ли лагать приложение?

Т.е. адаптер будет получать коллекцию из элементов из БД и будет выводить в список.

Я конечно понимаю что можно взять и проверить лагает или нет, но хочется услышать мнение опытных людей.

Comment: По идее логика правильная: записи из БД извлекаем и кладем в коллекцию (arraylist какой-нибудь) - коллекцию кидаем в адаптер ресайкла.
А какая БД?

Comment: Sqlite.. Просто мне интересно 50 тысяч записей в коллекцию класть и из коллекции в RecyclerView с точки зрения ресурсов нормально? или лучше другой подход

Comment: Если вы собираетесь доставать данные из БД, затем складывать их в коллекцию и из колекции выводить в список, то такое решение будет лагать на любом гаджете со 100% вероятностью. Решение [дилетанское и очень плохое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539153/177345) по многим параметрам. Есть общепринятое решение - выводить данные напрямую из `Cursor` в список [обязательно через `CursorLoader`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427870/177345). [Пример использования `CursorLoader`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612783/177345) (здесь ListView но сути это никак не меняет)

Answer (score 3):

Будет "лагать" или нет зависит от нескольких факторов:

1. Мощность гаджета
2. Какой объем данных у вас в одной записи в базе данных. Скажем, если у вас хранятся комментарии пользователей из условного сайта, то размер записи в базе данных может быть довольно большой. Как следствие, 50 000 записей это большой объем данных.
3. Как вы достаете данные из SQLite и кладете их коллекцию. Например, вы получаете данные из базы, но не напрямую их в коллекцию кладете, а перед этим формируете POJO-объекты, которые уже будут элементами вашей коллекции. Это дополнительные расходы.
4. Как вы формируете коллекцию. Скажем, вы используете в качестве коллекции `ArrayList`. Тогда желательно знать размер коллекции до ее создания, т.к. при использовании конструктора без параметров  `capacity = 10` по-умолчанию. При переполнении новая `capacity = oldCapacity * 3 / 2 + 1` и происходит копирование всех элементов в массив нового размера (`System.arrayCopy()`). Хоть операция копирования и вылизана до последней строчки, все равно она крайне дорогая.

Я недавно [задавал похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/758511/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-sqlite-%D0%B2-recyclerview-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD-%D0%B7). Большинство комментаторов, высказалось за то, что особой проблемы нет какой объем данных грузить за один раз из базы данных. Мое мнение из практики: это не совсем так, если грузить достаточно большие данные из базы, затем помещать их в коллекцию, затем в адаптер `RecyclerView`, тогда даже на топовых устройствах будет подтормаживать. Смотрите обсуждения в упомянутом вопросе, пробуйте и делайте свои выводы.

Вам можно посоветовать две стратегии оптимизации:

1. Использовать связку `SQLiteCursor` - `RecyclerView` напрямую, минуя промежуточную коллекцию. В таком подходе вы напрямую даете `cursor` c данными в `RecyclerView`. Вот реализация такого подхода: [CursorRecyclerViewAdapter](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59)
2. Подгружать данные не сразу все, а частями, по мере необходимости. Обзор таких подходов смотрите [здесь](http://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/). Недавно вышла от Google библиотека [Paging Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html), которая организует постраничную подгрузку, можете её глянуть.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Этот пример https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59 я смотрел и плохо понял как адаптировать для существующей БД. И примеров не нашел где было бы реализовано что-то похожее с готовой БД. Везде есть примеры, где создается БД.

Comment: Я не понимаю какая разница есть ли у вас уже база, или она формируется динамически. Вы же спрашиваете как доставать большой объем данных их базы? Да, если у вас уже есть готовая реализация `SQLiteOpenHelper`, вы как-то получаете там `cursor` c данными, затем данные из `cursor` отдаете в коллекцию, и из коллекции в `RecyclerView`, то все что вам нужно сделать, для использования подхода  `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter` это переписать ваш адаптер, и давать `cursor` с данными напрямую в адаптер.

Comment: все правильно, только в вашем вопросе большинство комментаторов высказалось за то, что нет проблемы в том случае, если в адаптер передавать напрямую `Cursor`. Если перегонять через промежуточный список, то 100% будут лаги. Так же настоятельно рекомендуется использовать `CursorLoader`

Comment: @pavlofff так же настоятельно рекомендуется изначально использовать БД Realm :)

Comment: @YaPV На самом деле noSQL решение подходит [далеко не для всех ситуаций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/625760/177345), в некоторых применениях и явно проигрывает "классической" реляционной БД. Имеется ввиду сам характер хранимых данных и их обработка, а не скорость работы.

Comment: @pavlofff я не буду спорить, т.к. мой опыт разработки оставляет желать лучшего. Но из Realm тянуть записи из БД можно всего одной строкой: 
RealmResults<Model> list. Кидаем этот list в адаптер и избавляемся от сотен строк кода, присущих sqlite. Если я не прав - поправьте меня :)

Comment: А есть какая-нибудь статья, где описано как работать с БД realm, а именно выводить данные в RecyclerView?

Comment: @Kolhoznik [оф. дока](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/) с огромной кучей примеров. 
чтобы вы понимали я не агитирую использовать realm. Скажу сугубо по своим ощущениям. Когда я открыл мир БД Realm, я послал sqlite далеко и надолго и больше никогда к ней не возвращался. Для всех моих дел, реалма хватает выше крыши.

Comment: Я хотя бы посмотрю что за БД, никогда не работал с ней. Может получится что-то и написать используя эту БД

Comment: @YaPV, полностью согласен на счет Realm. Когда начал им пользоваться, ощущения были, как будто новый год настал ))

Comment: @kulikovman так да, наблюдаю, что всё чаще в вакансиях требуют знания именно БД Realm.

Comment: Не разделю общих восторгов по поводу `Realm`. Во-первых, у них ленивая реализация, т.е. вы получаете данные непосредственно когда они начинают использоваться, поэтому прицепить бенчмарк, чтобы померить скорость работы достаточно нетривиально. По субъективным ощущениям выигрыша в скорости нет (по сравнению с SQLite). Во-вторых, `Realm` не поддерживает передачу объекта между потоками. Хорошо, если запрос легкий и все достаточно быстро работает, чтобы не тормозить `UI`. Для больших БД не стал бы  `Realm` использовать.